# Now what is an Oxford Cleric?

Tags: meaning

While I read through the Canterbury Tales, I noticed that the Oxford Cleric has nothing to do with the church. What does his title even mean.

Comment: I found this in a book that I received from school long ago. From a teacher. Also I don't know where, if not here, is appropriate for this.

Answer (score 4):

In the *Canterbury Tales* that character is not a cleric but a "**[clerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Clerk%27s_Tale)**". The *Oxford English Dictionary* lists an example from the *Canterbury Tales*, referring to that clerk ("A Clerc ther was of Oxenford"), under meaning 4.a., "A man (or woman) of book learning, one able to read and write; a scholar. (Now a historical archaism.)". So the correct translation of "Clerc of Oxenford" would be "a scholar from Oxford", not "an Oxford cleric", as it is commonly translated.

Comment: "Cleric" and "Clerk" do share a [common root](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=clerk). The Online Etymology Dictionary says: **clerk (n.)** "man ordained in the ministry," c. 1200, from Old English cleric and Old French clerc "clergyman, priest; scholar, student," both from Church Latin clericus "a priest," noun use of adjective meaning "priestly, belonging to the clerus" (see cleric). 

Modern bureaucratic usage is a reminder of the dark ages when clergy alone could read and write and were employed for that skill by secular authorities.

Comment: @Lostinfrance Yes, "cleric" is also the first meaning the OED lists under "clerk". (Note that the word in the text is "clerc", as cited in my answer, not "cleric"!) But since they explicitly list the character from the *Canterbury Tales* under another meaning, I think we can trust those experts that "cleric" is not the appropriate meaning here. That person is described in the text as a student of philosophy, so he isn't a cleric.

Comment: @what that sounds like a term that one could use to distinguish people who take their intellectual pursuits as one would take their religious dedication. But why do they call him a cleric to this day?

Comment: @DenÉnaFaskómilos I wouldn't know.

Comment: *almost one month later*            Through reviewing the wording so that I could understand better, the definition provided by Lostinfrance does not really match with the idea that he has no "secular" employment, which would mean he was connected to the church. Since he is not, then it must be certain that the actual modern equivalent would indeed be the definition @what used. But still why call him a cleric when nothing about him is relevant to that occupation?

Comment: @DenÉnaFaskómilos Did you even read my answer? In the *Canterbury Tales* that character is **not called a "cleric", but a "clerc"**.

Comment: @what that's what I meant by that. Reading over it, I see that it was vague, and I apologize. What I was trying to say was that clerc can be interpreted as a literate person, and an ordained minister, but the interpretation intended in the story is the one you gave. I still don't understand why they call him an actual cleric.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are referring to a parish clerk which is defined as "an official designated to carry out various duties, either for a church parish or a parish council." In terms of how it is presented in the story, the clerk would both educate and pray for people in exchange for borrowing money. It is also believed that the King in his story is supposed to represent God while the wife represents the people and their absolute obedience and dedication to God. He is the opposite of many of the other clergy members on the trip, like the Friar and the Monk, as the Clerk is kind, selfless, diligent, and respectful. The clerk's character is supposed to represent what members of the Church should strive to be as many abuse their power for wealth and lavish lifestyles.